# How to auto execute a command in screen window while creating a screen session

Tags: linux, ssh, display, gnu-screen

I have configured my .screen rc to create 10 windows while creating a screen session as

```
 screen -t task1      0
 screen -t task2      1
 screen -t task3      2
 .
 .
```

What I want is whenever I create a screen session, every window should ssh to a machine. I tried various stuff like

```
 screen -t task1      0 "ssh -p 22 root@x.x.x.x"

 screen -t task1      0 bash "ssh -p 22 root@x.x.x.x"
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the quoting.

```
screen -t task1 1 "ssh foo@bar"
screen -t task2 2 bash "ssh foo@bar"
```

The first line will try to execute a command called "`ssh foo@bar`" instead of splitting it into words; try without quotes.

The second line will instruct bash to execute a script called "`ssh foo@bar`" instead of parsing it as a command; that needs the `-c` flag:

```
screen -t task1 1 ssh foo@bar
screen -t task2 2 bash -c "ssh foo@bar"
```

To try out exactly what's happening, paste the commands from your screenrc to an interactive session. Assuming your command character is the default, try `^a:` to get the equivalent of a screen commandline.

```
^a:screen -t task1 2 "ssh foo@bar"
```

.. should give you the error message
`Cannot exec 'ssh foo@bar': No such file or directory`